# Usar o filter_input com array_filter($_POST)

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário onde tem bastante campos, para isso, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
require_once('classes/metodosClass.php');
$metodos = new metodosClass();
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Cadastrar"){
  $dados = array_filter($_POST);
  echo $metodos->cadastrarDados($dados);
}
```

E no método cadastrarDados($dados):

```
public function cadastrarDados(array $dados){
   $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$dados["Nome"]);
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$dados["Email"]);
   $cpf = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$dados["CPF"]);
   ....
   // Depois faço a inclusão no BD
}
```

Só que estou querendo aplicar o `FILTER_SANITIZE` e `FILTER_VALIDATE` para esses campos. Como eu poderia aplicar nessa situação já que estou usando o array? Pensei em fazer dessa forma, mas não sei se é a correta. Colocarei apenas o exemplo que pensei em fazer:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Cadastrar"){      
   $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
   $emailLimpar = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   $emailValidar = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
   ....
   if($emailValidar == true){
      $erro = "Favor colocar o e-mail corretamente!"; 
   }else if(...){
    .......
   }else{
     $dados = array_filter($_POST);
     echo $metodos->cadastrarDados($dados);
   }
}
```

Comment: Fiz um teste e infelizmente não funcionou. O `filter_input()` perde o valor quando é passado para o `array_filter()`. Teria alguma solução para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tá, então vamos supor que você esteja utilizando da arquitetura *MVC*, vamos seguir os preceitos do mesmo...

Supondo que o chamado do `$_POST` esteja no **Controller**, basicamente apenas iremos transformar ele em um `array()` e o resto deixamos para o **Model** fazer, inclusive filtrar...

Basicamente o que iriamos fazer? O que você já fez:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Cadastrar"){
  $dados = array_filter($_POST);
  echo $metodos->cadastrarDados($dados);
}
```

E vindo no **Model** com a filtragem do `array()`:

```
public function cadastrarDados(array $dados){
    $dadosFiltrado = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $dados, FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

    // Faça o restante dos filter_input aqui com o $dadosFiltrado (Inclusive as validações e verificações do email e ETC)
}
```

Veja se o mesmo funciona com o seu sistema! :)

Comment: Perfeito Rapha. Obrigado mais uma vez!